# A connection could not be established because the database name '<databaseName>' is larger than the maximum length allowed by the network protocol

Tags: apache-spark, jdbc, apache-spark-sql

We are trying to pull data using a JDBC connection request and spark 3.2.0. Our JDBC call using splice driver (com.splicemachine:db-client:2.7.0.1815) looks something like this with sample query -

```
val url_upd = "jdbc:splice://sl73caehdp0225.visa.com:1527/splicedb;user=***;password=a***"
val query = "select top 5 ENCRPT_PYMT_CRD_ACCT_NUM_NORM from optd.ttd_cs_dtl CS where TRAN_CD IN ('01','04','05','06','10','11')"

val jdbcDF = spark.read.format("jdbc").option("url", url).option("driver", "com.splicemachine.db.jdbc.ClientDriver").option("query", query).load();
```

And we are observing a limitation of "111" characters for the size of the query to get the results. If the size exceeds this limit, we are receiving the below error -

> "A connection could not be established because the database name '' is larger than the maximum length allowed by the network protocol."

The same connection request and query work fine in spark 2.3

Comment: Have you tried using actual SparkSQL functions rather than a raw string query?

Comment: This is Spark SQL only ? Are you suggesting raw query instead ?  But this is working fine spark2.x

Comment: No. I'm saying use DSL that Spark can optimize `select(..).where().sort().limit(5)`. Otherwise, the error is suggesting that your username and password together cannot be much longer than 50 or so characters.

Comment: the whole query is parsed as DB name, is it default in saprk3 or issue with driver maybe ? 

java.sql.SQLNonTransientConnectionException: A connection could not be established because the database name 'splicedb;url=jdbc:splice://sl73caehdp0225.visa.com:1527/splicedb;driver=com.splicemachine.db.jdbc.ClientDriver;query=select top 5 ENCRPT_PYMT_CRD_ACCT_NUM_NORM from optd.ttd_cs_dtl CS where ENCRPT_PYMT_CRD_ACCT_NUM_NORM IN ('cs_lKlVWWzKwCXSnvDhuwQAP','testing')' is larger than the maximum length allowed by the network protocol.

Comment: That seems to be a driver thing

Comment: how come its working in spark2 ?

Comment: I don't use Spark much. I cannot answer what has changed between versions. Still, as I said, you should try using proper DSL functions. Otherwise, `option("query"` value will always be appended to the connection string